# Difference between two presto jdbc

Tags: jdbc, hive, presto, trino

few days ago, I sent a query using presto.
it's really simple query like " select * from table limit 3; "
but, jdbc error was occured. I check my driver.

At that time, I used PrestoDB driver. Class name was 'com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver'
and I changed it to PrestoSQL driver using 'io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver' class.
I solved the query unexecution error. but, I'm curious why it wasn't work at the first time.

Anybody know why ?

Answer (score 4):

`com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver` - is a PrestoDB, aka Presto(tm) driver, last update in 2018

`io.prestosql.jdbc.PrestoDriver` - is a PrestoSQL driver, last update in 2019 (now the name is Trino, rebranded in 2020)

`io.trino.jdbc.TrinoDriver` -  Trino latest driver class.

So, which driver should be used depends on what you actually using: PrestoDB, PrestoSQL or Trino.

See also
[Presto JDBC driver name change for 300+ version](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.1.0?topic=administration-presto-driver-name-change) - I guess they meant Trino.

And thanks to @BrianOlsen for the comment with link, read the whole story: [Announcing Trino - blog](https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html)

Comment: Great answer, here's a little context as to why there are three drivers: https://trino.io/blog/2020/12/27/announcing-trino.html